# VSFTPD Not listing all directories

Tags: ftp, sftp, vsftpd, ftps

I am running into an odd situation where through various FTP clients, VSFTPD does not seem to return all directories in the directory listing.

You'll see here in the FTP client that the error, Historical, outgoing, reactivation, sample, and test folders are displayed.

[image]

However it is missing the directory process. As you can see below the folder has all the same permissions as the rest of the folders.

[image]

When I try and create the folder through the FTP client I get an error, which tells me that the server recognizes that the folder is there and won't allow it to be overridden, but I can't figure out why my FTP clients won't show the folder. We've tried with Filezilla, WinSCP, and Cyberduck. We are connecting via FTPS Explicit Auth TLS on port 21.

Comment: Does your vsftp config say anything about that directory? Does it have any ACLs?

Comment: Ahh yep there it is

hide_file={process}